# Datepicker and Timepicker text does not appear in Android 5.1.1

Tags: android, android-layout, android-datepicker, android-timepicker

[image: date and time picker looking like that in android 5.1.1]

code for my datepicker and timepicker is:

```
<DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:calendarTextColor="#000000"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
            android:calendarViewShown="false">
        </DatePicker>

        <TimePicker
            android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:numbersTextColor="#000000"
            android:amPmTextColor="#000000"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </TimePicker>
```

It looks perfact on other devices with different android versions. Please suggest how to solve this problem.

**EDIT:**
Android 5.1.1 uses different theme for date and time picker but i need to show the holo theme, so i changed date and time picker theme manually. it has changed but now its shows like the screenshot, i.e. text does not appear(or may be text is with white color). i also changed text color in xml code but it still does not appear. How can i make text vissible in this.

Comment: Hi @Rahul Sharma, I'm not quite sure what's the problem here. On the top I can vaguely see in white "Oct 23 2015" and at the bottom "2:06 PM". What exactly is the problem and what do you expect?

Comment: Hi @AuroMetal thanks for response, plz check edited for detail what i want.

Comment: Have you tried applying the theme **before** the text colors?

Comment: Yes i do that first, text was not appeared then i change text color

Comment: I guess its theme problem .set `@style/Theme.Holo` for testing case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found solution, i just changed theme of my `datepicker` and `timepicker` from 
                `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"`

to

```
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
```

and text appears now.